# How to understand, This part of debugging

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

Whenever I am debug my code I always facing this screen.
How to understand this screen?
Is it useful to us.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the human-readable version of the error try to write this line in debug area 
**po $arg1** or **po $rax**

Or add this line to **Exception Breakpoint**
[image]

The great article for this by link https://www.natashatherobot.com/xcode-debugging-trick/

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe how you got into this state?  It looks like you were stepping over a source line in some HomeWorkViewController method, and the step-over ended up stopped in a method in the Swift standard library called by that method.  That shouldn't happen, and sounds like a bug.

If this description is right, can you file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com and we'll try to figure out what's going wrong.